# Derive a rotational/transformational matrix given an image and a rotated image in Java?

Tags: affinetransform

Need some advise and point me in the right direction.

My object detection system reads in this image(see below) and returns coordinates for bounding boxes for some detection results(in this case, a hammer)

http://i1116.photobucket.com/albums/k572/Ruihong_Zhou/z3IJx-1.png

However I wish to examine the accuracy of the detection results for the same image by feeding the system, rotated images of the original images and allow it to detect and return coordinates for detection results if any.

For example:

http://i1116.photobucket.com/albums/k572/Ruihong_Zhou/myJQA-1.jpg

Let's say the coordinates of the yellow point(in the image above) is found but it is with respect to the rotated frame of reference. How do i actually transform/rotate these coordinates and find out where do they actually lie in the original image with respect to the original frame of reference.

Someone has pointed out to me that I should use affine transformation but I'm not sure how to go about it as honestly this is the 1st time i have heard of affine transformation and i'm still trying to brute force my learning of it now.

Further research indicates that I need both the original set of coordinates in the original image and the same set of coordinates in the rotated image to come up with a transformation matrice but I only have the detected set of coordinates in the rotated image.